# CacheBuilder using guava cache for query resultant

Tags: guava, hibernate-criteria

To reduce the DB hits to read the data from DB using the `query`, I am planning to keep resultant in the cache. To do this I am using guava caching.

**studentController.java**

```
public Map<String, Object> getSomeMethodName(Number departmentId, String departmentType){
    ArrayList<Student> studentList = studentManager.getStudentListByDepartmentType(departmentId, departmentType);
    ----------
    ----------
    }
```

**StudentHibernateDao.java**(criteria query )

```
@Override
    public ArrayList<Student> getStudentListByDepartmentType(Number departmentId, String departmentType) {
        Criteria criteria =sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Student.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("departmentId", departmentId));
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("departmentType", departmentType));
        ArrayList<Student> studentList = (ArrayList)criteria.list();
        return studentList;
    }
```

To cache the criteria query resultant i started off with building CacheBuilder, like below.

```
private static LoadingCache<Number departmentId, String departmentType, ArrayList<Student>> studentListCache = CacheBuilder
            .newBuilder().expireAfterAccess(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .maximumSize(1000)
            .build(new CacheLoader<Number departmentId, String departmentType, ArrayList<Student>>() {
                public ArrayList<Student> load(String key) throws Exception {
                    return getStudentListByDepartmentType(departmentId, departmentType);
                }
            });
```

Here I dont know where to put CacheBuilder function and how to pass multiple key parameters(i.e departmentId and departmentType) to `CacheLoader` and call it.

Is this the correct way of caching using `guava`. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

Guava's cache only accepts two type parameters, a key and a value type. If you want your key to be a compound key then you need to build a new *compound* type to encapsulate it. Effectively it would need to look like this (I apologize for my syntax, I don't use Java that often):

```
// Compound Key type
class CompoundDepartmentId {
  public CompoundDepartmentId(Long departmentId, String departmentType) {
    this.departmentId = departmentId;
    this.departmentType = departmentType;
  }
}

private static LoadingCache<CompoundDepartmentId, ArrayList<Student>> studentListCache = 
  CacheBuilder
    .newBuilder().expireAfterAccess(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    .maximumSize(1000)
    .build(new CacheLoader<CompoundDepartmentId, ArrayList<Student>>() {
      public ArrayList<Student> load(CompoundDepartmentId key) throws Exception {
        return getStudentListByDepartmentType(key.departmentId, key.departmentType);
      }
    });
```

Comment: how to call this in method of studentController.java file? will it remain same as in my question or do i need to change it.

Comment: Where are you keeping the cache? In the controller or the DAO?